# Como saber o número de arquivos numa pasta usando Java?

Tags: java, arquivo

Resumindo, dado um caminho que seja uma pasta do sistema, o retorno seja a quantidade de arquivos diretamente na raiz da pasta (não deve levar em consideração arquivos em subpastas). Isso seria usado numa iteração com for para acessar os arquivos para fazer um "parseamento" (reconheça algumas informações).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a interface `FileFilter` pra isso:

```
File f = new File("/home/user/pasta");

File[] files = f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.isFile();
    }
});

System.out.println(files.length);
```

O método `accept` da inteface `FileFilter` é chamado pra cada arquivo da pasta em questão. No caso em tela é feito um teste se o item é um arquivo (`isFile()`), caso seja, retorna true e o arquivo entra no vetor que será retornado.

Em Java 8 você poderia lançar mão do Lambda:

```
File file = new File("/home/user/pasta");

Arrays.stream(file.listFiles())
        .filter(f -> f.isFile())
        .forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Onde está sendo executado o `System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath())` você poderia chamar a rotina que faz o parser do arquivo.

Para contar os arquivos faça isso:

```
long quantidade = Arrays.stream(file.listFiles())
        .filter(f -> f.isFile())
        .count();
```

Comment: Essa solução é bem interessante,isso elimina a necessidade de ter que criar um laço somente para conter os arquivos. +1

Answer (score 3):

Crie uma instância da classe File contendo o caminho ao qual deseja-se obter o número total de arquivos.

```
File pasta = new File("/caminho/do/diretorio");
```

Agora basta criar um array com os arquivos utilizando o método `listFiles()` Depois iteramos sobre esse array contando o número de arquivos, sem mais delongas ficaria assim:

```
int contador = 0;
File pasta = new File("/caminho/do/diretorio");
File[] lista = pasta.listFiles();

for (File file : lista) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        contador ++;
    }
}
```

Desse modo você não conta as pastas do diretório, caso queira descobrir o número total de arquivos contando as pastas, basta fazer `lista.length`

*Att.*