# Ler nome de Arquivo Interno

Tags: java

Preciso realizar a leitura do nome dos arquivos contidos dentro de um pacote, por exemplo, ler o nome `file01.txt`, como na imagem abaixo :

[image: pacote com arquivos]

Assim posso percorrer o pacote `arquivos` sem ter a necessidade de nomear um arquivo para a leitura.

Comment: Relacionada (se não for duplicada): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159121/3084

Answer (score 6):

Pode fazer com `listFiles` ou [Files.walk](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) do Java 8.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final File pasta = new File("C:\\teste");
        listaArquivos(pasta);   
        listaArquivosJava8(pasta);
    }

    public static void listaArquivos(final File pasta) {
        for (final File fileEntry : pasta.listFiles()) {
            if (! fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void listaArquivosJava8(final File pasta) {
        try(Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(pasta.toURI()))) {
            paths.forEach(filePath -> {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                    System.out.println(filePath);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Fonte: [Read all files in a folder - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846349/1964435)

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos! Já estava prestes a editar com uma versão do java8 :p

Comment: E eu mal pude ver os movimentos de você e quem mais postou o `listFiles()` :P mas eu já estava escrevendo com essa opção desde o princípio

Comment: Valeu a força brother, mas, os arquivos estão "dentro do projeto", caminho absoluto não rola.

Comment: @ulk' Preciso fazer um teste aqui, mas esse deve ser fácil de resolver, vide: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15574/3117

Comment: Beleza Math, fico no aguardo parceiro.

Answer (score 4):

Tente o seguinte:

```
String path = getClass().getResource("arquivos").getPath();

File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();

for(File file : files){
  System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

Lembrando que o `path` só será recuperado corretamente da forma como indicada no código, levando em conta que a pasta `arquivos` faça parte do projeto. Se for externa, você precisa informar o caminho absoluto, como na [resposta do @Joe Torres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159931/28595)

Comment: Salve Diego, então fera, a estrutura do projeto está como na imagem, teria que referenciá-la no Build Path também ?

Comment: @ulk' não, basta usar dessa forma da resposta mesmo. O `getClass()` recupera a classe atual e o `getResource()` recupera o caminho do pasta informada, no caso `arquivos`, e o `getPath()` pega o caminho absoluto desta pasta. Este código foi testado utilizando uma estrutura semelhante a sua, pode testar que ele vai funcionar.

Comment: testei nesta estrutura e o `getClass().getResource("arquivos").getPath()` me retornou nullo, mesmo a pasta `arquivos` sendo um package do projeto.

Comment: Tenta botar uma barra: `getClass().getResource("/arquivos").getPath()` se a IDE acusar erro de sintaxe, coloque duas. a pasta arquivos no seu projeto está numa hierarquia diferente da sua classe java.

Answer (score 3):

Olha amigo, to meio enferrujado em java, mas até onde me lembro, você consegue listar os arquvos dessa forma:

```
File folder = new File("c:\pathproprojeto\src\arquivos");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

Comment: Joe, valeu a força fera, mas por caminho absoluto não rola.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void getImgs(String path){
File file = new File(path);
File[] arquivos = file.listFiles();

for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
    System.out.println(arquivo);
}
}
```