# Escolher um arquivo "x" dentro de um diretório em java

Tags: java, netbeans

Então, eu estou fazendo um projeto e nele eu teria que buscar algumas palavras chaves em arquivos .txt dentro de um determinado diretório, só que o nome desses arquivos não segue um padrão e meu programa teria que ler 1 por 1. Eu gostaria de saber se existe algum método em Java que consegue selecionar um arquivo baseado apenas no seu diretório e a posição em que se encontra no mesmo, por exemplo "encontre o caminho do 3 arquivo na pasta tal"

Comment: O que seria o seu ler? São arquivos *.TXT e tu vai ter que acessar o conteúdo dos arquivos?

Comment: Isso, desculpe, vou editar a pergunta, mas são arquivos txt e eu teria que rodar o texto em busca de algumas palavras chaves

Comment: Mas a parte de extrair o texto eu já fiz, o problema em questão seria o caminho de cada arquivo já que os nomes não são padronizados.

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa pergunta, vê se te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159928/ler-nome-de-arquivo-interno/159934#159934 Acredito que seja bem o que você precisa

Comment: Isso mesmo bro, brigadão pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void getImgs(String path){
File file = new File(path); // Diretório dos arquivos
File[] arquivos = file.listFiles();

for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
    System.out.println(arquivo); // Exibe o nome dos arquivos no diretório determinado
}
}
```